# Navigate to another page from flyout

Tags: winrt-xaml

Is it possible to navigate to another page when a flyout popup in the settings charm is shown in Windows 8. I want to be able to navigate to another page when a button is clicked in the flyout popup

Answer (score 4):

If this is your page that you want to display....

```
public sealed partial class PageToNavigateTo: LayoutAwarePage
{
     //Code stuff for page
}
```

your flyout code will look like this...

```
private void NavigationClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageToNavigateTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You control the settings charm Popups yourself - they are part of your UI, so you can do whatever you want from there, including navigating to another page.